# How can I identify an element that resides in an iframe without using an absolute xpath?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm writing a Selenium Script to check the number of rows in a page :

The rows are in an iframe so I couldn't not use /*[starts-with(@id, 'someid') to find number of elements as selenium webdriver is unable to locate elements inside an iframe using id or relative xpath. Only the absolute xpath is working.

My absolute xpath of my rows are as such

Row 1:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]
```

Row 2:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[5]/td[1]
```

Hence how to use starts with using the absolute xpath that starts with the following:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[
```

HTML

```html
<iframe id="MasterSplitter_mainContent_ASPxPageControlManageProgramme_ucEnrolment_Programme_Details_CBPnlDetail_ucFunding_GrantCalculator_pcGC_CIF-1" title="" src="../Funding/FundingGrantCalculator.aspx?SessionKey=k6ML680ffjM3LcWqMwUzNOe33dRU4xgBxVoW%2ftYHVWJs1Re6Yr4oTA%3d%3d"
  scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" xpath="1">


<tr ng-repeat-start="funding in data.fundings" ng-show="data.fundings.length > 0 &amp;&amp; !ShowLoading" ng-class="GetFundingRowCSSClass(funding)" data-qo-theme="danger" data-nq-tooltip="" data-qo-placement="top-center" data-qs-title="" class="ng-scope AvailableFunding" style="">

<tr ng-repeat-start="funding in data.fundings" ng-show="data.fundings.length > 0 &amp;&amp; !ShowLoading" ng-class="GetFundingRowCSSClass(funding)" data-qo-theme="danger" data-nq-tooltip="" data-qo-placement="top-center" data-qs-title="" class="ng-scope AvailableFunding" xpath="1">

</iframe>
```

Comment: The rows are in a iframe so I couldn't not use `/*[starts-with(@id, 'someid')` , it's a wrong perception, all you have to do is to switch to iframe and write the locator of rows. Share your HTML code of at least 2 rows.

Comment: Am I blind or is there no`iframe` element present in the given `HTML`?  Moreover, I cannot find any element listed which has an `id` tag.  I believe more context is required to identify the desired element.

If the `iframe` element is outside the above HTML, one must identify that element uniquely before proceeding to find any elements that reside within.

Comment: I have included the HTML, the elements are inside the iframe. I have tried switching to iframe but for some reason the webdriver is only able to locate elements using absolute xpaths when it is residing inside iframe.

Comment: How did you switch to iframe ?

Comment: driver.SwitchTo().Frame("MasterSplitter_mainContent_ASPxPageControlManageProgramme_ucEnrolment_Programme_Details_CBPnlDetail_ucFunding_GrantCalculator_pcGC_CIF-1");

Comment: try with this `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(By.CssSelector("iframe[id*='MasterSplitter_mainContent']"))` , and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @M.ila Just so you know, ( although perhaps this is a typo), you will always need to specify a locator strategy such as `By.CssSelector()` chosen by @cruisepandy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the curent focus is on browser window and number of rows is to be fetched from frames. Therefore, the focus has be move to Frame.

This is done using SwichTo() method. driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0). Here 0 denotes if only one frame is opened.
Frames can be selected by Frameindex, FrameName, and IwebElement.

After switching to Frame, xpath is used to list all the tr nodes.

//tr[contains(@ng-repeat-start,"funding in data.fundings")

Answer (score 2):

First you need to switch to iframe, for that you may use this code :

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(By.CssSelector("iframe[id*='MasterSplitter_mainContent']"));
```

Once you are inside the frame you can use this `xpath` to list all the `tr` nodes.

```
//tr[contains(@ng-repeat-start,"funding in data.fundings")
```

Comment: This looks great provided there is only one matching iframe found on the page. Nice.

Comment: `int numofrows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[contains(@ng-repeat-start,\"funding in data.fundings)\")")).Count;`catching exception `"invalid expression."` during test run